# How can I solve a Limited access network issue?

Tags: networking, internet, wireless-router, dhcp

I live in Venezuela and here the internet provider I have is called "Cantv" and I haven't had issues with my internet connection until now. Whenever the lights of my modem indicate that it's active and sending/receiving network packets I don't really have network access unless I release and renew the IP address manually from the command console (cmd). I discovered that by doing that I got a normal internet access for the moment; and by the way, I can't assure you guys that I fully knew "what I was doing" but it worked, it solved the problem...

Now, the real problem is that whenever I need to access the internet on a different computer/laptop I have to release and renew the IP over and over, and essentially it works as I said, but it's not the way it's supposed to "work". Also, it's not like a normal process that I can do on a Videogame console or in an Android Device by their lack of a terminal or console. I wish you could help me solve this issue, please.

I have a [Linksys WRT54G](http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WRT54GL/) router and a [Huawei SmartAX MT882](http://market.huawei.com/hwgg/access/en/products/cpe_portfolio1.html) provided by "Cantv".

And also, the gateway address that worked was `201.248.128.1` and the one that doesn't was the default one (`192.168.1.1`).

Comment: Hi. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be caused by some erroneous [`NAT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) configuration.

Your router **should** do this for you, because routing several (different) computers through one internet address/WAN endpoint is the main task of a router.

Thing is that `201.248.128.1` is a public IP address and `192.168.1.1` is a private IP address.

---

To elaborate on that description: This quotes from the [whole IPv4 range table](http://www.vlsm-calc.net/ipclasses.php):

```
Class  1st Octet      1st Octet High   Network/Host ID       Default Subnet    Number of            Hosts per Network
       Decimal Range  Order Bits       (N=Network, H=Host)   Mask              Networks             (Usable Addresses) 

A        1 – 126*     0                N.H.H.H               255.0.0.0         26 (27 – 2)          16,777,214 (224 – 2)
B      128 – 191      10               N.N.H.H               255.255.0.0       16,382 (214 – 2)         65,534 (216 – 2)
C      192 – 223      110              N.N.N.H               255.255.255.0     2,097,150 (221 – 2)         254 (28 – 2)
D      224 – 239      1110             Reserved for Multicasting
E      240 – 254      1111             Experimental; used for research
```

and this is the subset of private IPv4 ranges:

```
Class   Private Networks       Subnet Mask   Address Range
A       10.0.0.0               255.0.0.0     10.0.0.0    - 10.255.255.255
B       172.16.0.0-172.31.0.0  255.240.0.0   172.16.0.0  - 172.31.255.255
C       192.168.0.0            255.255.0.0   192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

So `201.248.128.1` is a public address(external) and `192.168.1.1` is a private address(internal).

**Any router should always have both!**